# Energy lost by friction if two blocks sliding past each other until stop, equal mass, equal/opposite velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Hoping this is a quick question. But lets say two blocks traveling equal and opposite directions, equal speeds and mass, were to make contact and slide past each other. Lets say they were long enough or slow enough that this would cause them to stop.

All the kinetic energy would become heat I know. But looking at this in terms of forces and work, would both friction forces on each block be doing negative work? Since both friction forces would be slowing down the other block, while converting it to heat.

Seemed wrong but i cannot find a better explanation. The energy has to go somewhere. I am ignoring other friction, air resistance, and compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, friction is doing negative work on each block, since the direction of the friction force is opposite the direction of movement of the block. Negative work means friction is taking the kinetic energy away from each block and dissipating it as heat. By the work energy theorem the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Since the change in kinetic energy of each block is negative, that means the net work done on each block has to be negative.

> Okay that makes sense. It just seemed odd to me. Mainly because when
> there is negative work, there is positive work in many cases.

Yes in many cases there is positive work also. But not in this case. In this case the only force acting on the boxes is the friction force and therefore the only work done on the boxes is the negative friction work. If, on the other hand, someone or something were apply a force on each box equal to the friction force so that the box continued to move at constant velocity, then that someone or something would be doing positive work exactly equal to the negative work done by friction, for a net work of zero and a change in kinetic energy of zero per the work-energy theorem.

> However here, in this case, the forces exist only to stop the blocks.
> So friction is stealing power and energy from both blocks causing them
> to stop. Got it

Yes, you got it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. It just seemed odd to me. Mainly because when there is negative work, there is positive work in many cases. However here, in this case, the forces exist only to stop the blocks. So friction is stealing power and energy from both blocks cuasing them to stop. Got it

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Yes you got it. See the update to my answer. Hope it acceptably answers your question.